# prevent curl from directly echo/output returned data

Tags: php, curl

I did a Post request with Curl on PHP. The instagram API returns a small json with the status. But somehow my code echos it and I want to get it to a variable instead.

```
//open connection
$ch = curl_init();

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//close connection
curl_close($ch);
```

Why does it echo or print the $result instead of just keeping it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to add `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);` before `curl_exec()`.

I don't know why curl doesn't just return by default.

Comment: Thank you. Its really weird though :D